# pyspark: Equivalent to SparkSession.getActiveSession() in pySpark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In pySpark 3, there is the [`SparkSession.getActiveSession()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.getActiveSession.html) command to receive the active Spark session. This command is available since Spark 3.0.

Is there a way to get the active session similarly in Spark 2.4? One option is `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`, which returns the active session if there is already one active. Otherwise it creates on. Is there a better way to just try to get the active session and return `None` or raise an exception if there is no active session?

Comment: Maybe reproduce the [implementation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/session.html#SparkSession.getActiveSession)? I can't test right now, but I think it can work even in Spark 2.4 as `getActiveSession` do exist in Scala-Spark 2.4.